# Haskell basic - pattern matching vs list tail

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, tail

I'm doing [Set7.hs](https://github.com/moocfi/haskell-mooc/blob/master/exercises/Set7.hs) from [haskell.mooc.fi/](https://haskell.mooc.fi/) [Exercises7](https://haskell.mooc.fi/part1#exercises-6)

```
-- Ex 5: reverse a NonEmpty list.
--
-- PS. The Data.List.NonEmpty type has been imported for you

-- below doesn't work
-- reverseNonEmpty :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
-- reverseNonEmpty  (h:|tail) = head reversed :| (tail reversed)
--   where 
--     reversed = reverse (h:tail)

-- below works
reverseNonEmpty :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
reverseNonEmpty (h :| tail) = head reversed :| revTail
  where
    reversed = reverse (h : tail)
    -- revTail = (tail reversed) - this doesn't work, but WHY???
    (_:revTail) = reversed
```

error message is:

```
Set7.hs:152:15: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a] -> t’ with actual type ‘[a]’
    • The function ‘tail’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘[a]’ has none
      In the expression: tail reversed
      In an equation for ‘revTail’: revTail = tail reversed
    • Relevant bindings include
        revTail :: t (bound at Set7.hs:152:5)
        reversed :: [a] (bound at Set7.hs:151:5)
        tail :: [a] (bound at Set7.hs:149:23)
        h :: a (bound at Set7.hs:149:18)
        reverseNonEmpty :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
          (bound at Set7.hs:149:1)
    |
152 |     revTail = tail reversed
```

I don't understand error message, what's wrong with `tail reversed`?

Why version with pattern matching `(_:revTail) = reversed` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reverseNonEmpty (h :| tail) = ...`

You've bound the name `tail` yourself, to refer to the list part of the `NonEmpty`. So this shadows the normal `tail` function, and there's no way to refer to that inside the body of `reverseNonEmpty`.

This is why the error message is telling you that `tail` has type `[a]` and can't be applied to an argument.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid these issues I strongly recommend you compile your code with warnings enabled. You can use the GHC flag `-Wall` for that.

With warnings on, GHC spots the issue:

```
<source>:6:23: warning: [GHC-63397] [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for `tail' shadows the existing binding
      imported from `Prelude' at <source>:1:1
      (and originally defined in `GHC.List')
  |
6 | reverseNonEmpty (h :| tail) = head reversed :| revTail
  |                       ^^^^
```

GHC here warns that there are two things in scope and both are named `tail`. One is the library function, the other is the local variable bound through pattern matching.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said. Please don't use variable names with the same name as already existing ones in an outer scope. You assigned `tail` to the tail of the input, so that will not work.

I however think that the intend was to write the reverse through recursion. We can recurse with:

```
reverseNonEmpty :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
reverseNonEmpty (h :| t) = go t [h]
  where
    go [] ys = …
    go (x : xs) ys = …
```

where I leave implementing the `…` parts as an exercise.